# Changing autogenerated makefile template in CDT Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, auto-generate

I just wonder if is it possible to edit autogenerated makefile or makefile template in Eclipse CDT. What I want to do is make diffrent folders structure. I would like to get something like:

> ../prj_folder 
>   --../bin <-- here goes all my executable files 
>   --../src <-- here are all my .cpp files 
>   --../include <-- .hh files 
>   --../obj <-- .o files 
>   etc.

I know that I can make my own makefile to do it, but it would be really nice to generate it automatically and don't waste my time on creating one manually. Is this even possible or have to make every makefile by myself from scratch? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
kodi-16.

Comment: I think this is done by the `CDT Builder`, you may implement your own builder plugin.